# can't add support library use compile() in dependencies build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I read how to add support repository from google dev site
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/support-library/setup.html
and result in error on build file

I can't find any resolution on relate topic

this is my build.gradlew

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

and I get compile result

```
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:support:23.1.0] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@37f86333.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up [buildscript dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:external_dependencies) with [configuration dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0"
    }
}

// ...

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0"
}
```

Comment: Thank ,but how I can get any reference of what both dependencies stand for .

Comment: @NitiSantikul - have added links to my answer.